# Get the path of an element

Tags: xslt, xpath

is there a XPath function, which returns the absolute path of an element, so I can use it in sth. like:

```
<xsl:if test="path() = /root/parent/child">
   ...
</xsl:if>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test if two nodes are the same, you must use generate-id():

```
<xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(/root/parent/child)">
   <!-- The current node is the same as /root/parent/child -->
   ...
</xsl:if>
```

generate-id() returns an unique ID for each node of the document.

Comment: I want to test if a node has an ancestor (to be detailed: the parent of the parent of the node) with a specific name. These nodes match with another template, but they should not.

I fixed it now with proper match statements. Thanks, though.

Comment: To solve this problem punischdude had to write the proper path thats it .. But @Erlok has given Good idea .. anyways .. I din't know about generate-id(.) ..

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, but such expression '. = /root/parent/child' returns boolean and means the same.

Comment: but you may use @match of xsl:template to select node you need, more precisely.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean the same; with this XPath expression you check the egality of the text content of both nodes, not their identity.